# asp.net dont load ajax control

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have write a asp.net page with a ajax control calendar with this is the code:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Calendario1.aspx.cs" Inherits="IntraFaz.Calendario1" %>
 <%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <H2> Controle Calendario Ajax            </H2>
<p> 
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
</p>
<p> Data de Inicio:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="20px" 
        ImageUrl="~/calendar.png" Width="20px" />
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
        Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
</p>

</asp:Content>
```

I try load via localhost and in IIS 6 with with asp.net 4.030 and return me this error

[image]

This is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;  Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="MXFimConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MAQ001;Initial Catalog=MXFim;User ID=sa;Password=admin2012" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies>
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
    </configuration>
```

I have re-installed Ajax 3 times. Thanks by abny orientation 
Alejandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem re instaling AjaxControlToolkit with Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the control tags into your web.config..

```
<controls>
     <add tagPrefix="asp" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
     namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
</controls>
```

Comment: I have add this line to the webconfig , its wrong the problem continues

Answer (score 0):

I have re install the Ajax Toolkit with Nuget, and all works fine